# How to re-order columns in a frequency table (OTU/ASV table)? Samples are out of order

Tags: r, bioinformatics

My lab is looking to analyze 30 environmental samples containing NGS data. My when I tar'd the tar.bz2 file, the fastq files that were released were out of order in the new directory. I didn't think anything of it and figured the order would be simply be corrected as I progressed through my workflow. This didn't happen. Now in the frequency table my sample columns out of order. Here is an example of what I mean:

| sample-B1 | sample-B4 | sample-B3 | sample-B2 | species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 4 | 8 | dog |
| 14 | 3 | 10 | 9 | cat |

I want to change the sample columns to order B1-B4 like so:

| sample-B1 | sample-B2 | sample-B3 | sample-B4 | species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 | 4 | 0 | dog |
| 14 | 9 | 10 | 3 | cat |

This is a simplification. In my actual data I have 30 "sample" columns. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_sort` on the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
   select(str_sort(names(.), numeric = TRUE))
```

-output

```
df1
#  sample-B1 sample-B2 sample-B3 sample-B4 species
#1         2         8         4         0     dog
#2        14         9        10         3     cat
```

---

Or another option is `mixedsort` from `gtools`

```
df1 <- df1[gtools::mixedsort(names(df1))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`sample-B1` = c(2L, 14L), `sample-B4` = c(0L, 
3L), `sample-B3` = c(4L, 10L), `sample-B2` = 8:9, species = c("dog", 
"cat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response akrun! I tried out df1 <- df1[gtools::mixedsort(names(df1))] and that seemed to do the trick! Much appreciated :)